# Cannot save decision tree plot using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

The font is too small to be visualized so I wish to save the image and view it locally instead of on Jupyter.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1,ncols = 1,figsize = (4,4), dpi=300)
tree.plot_tree(clf,filled=True,rounded=True)
plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

However, the saved image is totally blank.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try plotting on the ax:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1,ncols = 1,figsize = (4,4), dpi=300)
tree.plot_tree(clf,filled=True,rounded=True, ax=axes)
plt.savefig('foo.png')
```